# How do I find the electric field above the center of a square plate (rather than circular)?

Tags: electromagnetism

I tried to integrate E due to a line of charge sweeping across the plate, but got bogged down. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you be a bit more speciffic?

Comment: Yes, more details would be good. Are you talking about a 2D plate with a uniform surface charge density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to this one is knowing how to do the integral. I am going to assume you got an integral that looks like $$\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \frac{a \lambda dx}{(x^2+d^2)^{3/2}}.$$
The first thing to do to make this easier is non-dimensionalize the integral. Let's start by switching to a non-dimensional integration variable $u=x/L$. Then $dx = L du$. Our integral becomes $$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \frac{a \lambda L du}{((Lu)^2+d^2)^{3/2}}.$$
Now let's pull dimensional factors outside of the integral. We get $$\frac{a \lambda L}{d^2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \frac{du}{((Lu/d)^2+1)^{3/2}}.$$
We will forget about the prefactor right now and concentrate on the integral. The denominator is complicated and we want to simplify it. We are going to simplify with the identy $\tan^2 \theta + 1 = sec^2 \theta$. We will need to make the substition $\tan \theta = Lu/d$. Then $du = \frac{d}{L} \sec^2 \theta d\theta$. The integral is now 
$$\int_{-\theta_0}^{\theta_0} \frac{\frac{d}{L} \sec^2 \theta d\theta}{(\tan^2 \theta+1)^{3/2}},$$
where $\theta_0 = \tan^{-1} \frac{L}{2d}$. After simplifying the integral, we get
$$\frac{d}{L} \int_{-\theta_0}^{\theta_0}\cos \theta d\theta,$$
so we are good. This technique is called [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trig_sub).

Comment: I totally answered the wrong question. I thought it was a square, not a whole 2d plate. If you do that whole plate, then you get an integral which is hard to evaluate. I certainly don't know how to do it besides looking it up.